# Can anyone decipher a flash CS4 crash log?

Tags: flash, logging, crash, cs4

I have just updated to Snow Leopard and one of my important Flash files is now crashing every time I compile. I am hoping that someone can help decipher this crash log and offer any tips on what the problem might be. Flash does not give an error message, just compiles then hangs until I use "Force Quit". The swf actually does get generated, but obviously I need to fix this crashing problem. Happens every single time with this FLA. It's just an asset FLA with no code.

```
Process:         Adobe Flash CS4 [1194]
Path:            /Applications/Adobe Flash CS4/Adobe Flash CS4.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash CS4
Identifier:      com.adobe.flash-10.0
Version:         10.0.2.566 (10.0.2)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [152]

Date/Time:       2010-04-15 12:13:49.551 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D578)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000a70
Crashed Thread:  17  Java: VM Thread

Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libFontRegistry.dylib           0x9075f6f2 XTSendCopyFontForCharacter + 188
3   libFontRegistry.dylib           0x9077278f TGlobalFontRegistryImp::CopyFontForCharacter(unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned int) const + 163
4   libFontRegistry.dylib           0x9075f46c XTCopyFontForCharacter + 187
5   com.apple.CoreText              0x91616d7f TDescriptorSource::CopySystemWideFallbackDescriptor(CGFont*, unsigned short const*, long) const + 165
6   com.apple.CoreText              0x91629df2 TBaseFont::CreateDescriptorForCharacters(__CFArray const*, unsigned short const*, long, CFRange&, bool) const + 244
7   com.apple.CoreText              0x91610db1 TFont::InitDescriptor(TFont const&, unsigned short const*, long, CFRange&) + 111
8   com.apple.CoreText              0x9161199c TFont::TFont(TFont const&, unsigned short const*, long, CFRange&) + 50
9   com.apple.CoreText              0x9160feb8 CTFontCreateForCharacterRange + 128
10  com.apple.QD                    0x995cce0a TFontCascadeList::FindFontsForCharacters(unsigned short const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long*, unsigned long*) + 150
11  com.apple.QD                    0x995d40d5 TTextLineLayout::SubstituteFonts(TATSUGlyphRecordArray*, unsigned char*) + 2441
12  com.apple.QD                    0x995d46fc TTextLineLayout::MapUnmappedGlyphs(TATSUGlyphRecordArray*) + 40
13  com.apple.QD                    0x995d4a5b TTextLineLayout::ConstructGlyphRecordArrayWithRegularGlyphs(TATSUGlyphRecordArray*, unsigned long*) + 551
14  com.apple.QD                    0x99556ebf TTextLineLayout::ConstructGlyphRecordArray(TATSUGlyphRecordArray*, TLayoutControls*) + 671
15  com.apple.QD                    0x995d4b63 TTextLineLayout::ConstructAndLayoutGlyphArray(TATSUGlyphRecordArray*, ATSLineLayoutLineParams*, TLayoutControls*, long, unsigned long) + 227
16  com.apple.QD                    0x995560c6 TTextLineLayout::MeasureText(unsigned long, unsigned long, long*, long*, long*, long*) + 568
17  com.apple.QD                    0x99555e7a ATSUGetUnjustifiedBounds + 107
18  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00a7578e 0x1000 + 10962830
19  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00a768be 0x1000 + 10967230
20  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00a76f1f 0x1000 + 10968863
21  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00990ce9 0x1000 + 10026217
22  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00992b0d 0x1000 + 10033933
23  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00aa2f56 0x1000 + 11149142
24  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00aa43b9 0x1000 + 11154361
25  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00aa4d11 0x1000 + 11156753
26  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00a2c217 0x1000 + 10662423
27  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x008ee851 0x1000 + 9361489
28  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x008ee9ba 0x1000 + 9361850
29  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x008ef7c8 0x1000 + 9365448
30  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x008f8cfd 0x1000 + 9403645
31  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00a8dbb8 0x1000 + 11062200
32  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00a2ae34 0x1000 + 10657332
33  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0090be21 0x1000 + 9481761
34  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0090a752 0x1000 + 9475922
35  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0062f7bf 0x1000 + 6481855
36  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00454e8b 0x1000 + 4537995
37  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00bdf1e2 0x1000 + 12444130
38  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0098ce99 0x1000 + 10010265
39  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00da1441 TTimerTask<LPeriodical>::TTimerTask(LPeriodical*, void (LPeriodical::*)(LTimerTask*)) + 201
40  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00b459e7 0x1000 + 11815399
41  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x90d8c76b __CFRunLoopRun + 8059
42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x90d8a0f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x90d89f21 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
44  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x96dad0fc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 392
45  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x96dacded ReceiveNextEventCommon + 158
46  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x96f351d4 _AcquireNextEvent + 54
47  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x96f2af20 RunApplicationEventLoop + 228
48  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00993fed 0x1000 + 10039277
49  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0089ed33 0x1000 + 9035059
50  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0089edde 0x1000 + 9035230
51  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00003742 0x1000 + 10050
52  com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00003669 0x1000 + 9833

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bbb42 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bc25c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bb719 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bb4be _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907baf41 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bad86 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795342 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2eb8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9080b42f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.adobe.amt.services          0x0bd20552 AMTConditionLock::LockWhenCondition(int) + 46
4   com.adobe.amt.services          0x0bd1b995 _AMTThreadedPCDService::PCDThreadWorker(_AMTThreadedPCDService*) + 115
5   com.adobe.amt.services          0x0bd205b0 AMTThread::Worker(void*) + 20
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97289de8 TS_exception_listener_thread + 160
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x205c0d84 ExternalPlayer_Initialize + 2117252
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795342 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2eb8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9080b42f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203af27f 0x200ab000 + 3162751
4   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203d32ff ExternalPlayer_Initialize + 95231
5   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203af72f 0x200ab000 + 3163951
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795342 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2eb8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9080b42f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203af27f 0x200ab000 + 3162751
4   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203d32ff ExternalPlayer_Initialize + 95231
5   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203af72f 0x200ab000 + 3163951
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795342 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2eb8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9080b42f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203af27f 0x200ab000 + 3162751
4   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203d32ff ExternalPlayer_Initialize + 95231
5   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203af72f 0x200ab000 + 3163951
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795342 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2eb8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9080b42f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203af27f 0x200ab000 + 3162751
4   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203d32ff ExternalPlayer_Initialize + 95231
5   ...ia.Flash Player.authplaylib  0x203af72f 0x200ab000 + 3163951
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 9:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c3262 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2f1e _pthread_cond_wait + 1191
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c4bb8 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 73
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971f6aee TSWaitOnCondition + 126
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971e243d TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 202
5   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971dde0f MPWaitOnQueue + 250
6   AdobeACE                        0x04b9538d 0x4b64000 + 201613
7   AdobeACE                        0x04b94d85 0x4b64000 + 200069
8   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971c1eb6 PrivateMPEntryPoint + 68
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 10:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c3262 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2f1e _pthread_cond_wait + 1191
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c4bb8 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 73
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971f6aee TSWaitOnCondition + 126
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971e243d TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 202
5   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971dde0f MPWaitOnQueue + 250
6   AdobeACE                        0x04b9538d 0x4b64000 + 201613
7   AdobeACE                        0x04b94d85 0x4b64000 + 200069
8   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971c1eb6 PrivateMPEntryPoint + 68
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 11:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c3262 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2f1e _pthread_cond_wait + 1191
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c4bb8 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 73
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971f6aee TSWaitOnCondition + 126
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971e243d TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 202
5   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971dde0f MPWaitOnQueue + 250
6   AdobeACE                        0x04b9538d 0x4b64000 + 201613
7   AdobeACE                        0x04b94d85 0x4b64000 + 200069
8   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971c1eb6 PrivateMPEntryPoint + 68
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 12:  Java: Exception Handler Thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90801048 mach_msg_server + 520
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610fe25 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 61045
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610fdca JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 60954
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 13:  Java: Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e928 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55672
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e588 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54744
6   libclient.dylib                 0x26124931 jio_vsnprintf + 321
7   libclient.dylib                 0x2612486a jio_vsnprintf + 122
8   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 14:  Java: Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e928 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55672
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e588 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54744
6   libclient.dylib                 0x26124931 jio_vsnprintf + 321
7   libclient.dylib                 0x2612486a jio_vsnprintf + 122
8   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 15:  Java: Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e928 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55672
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e588 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54744
6   libclient.dylib                 0x26124931 jio_vsnprintf + 321
7   libclient.dylib                 0x2612486a jio_vsnprintf + 122
8   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 16:  Java: Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e928 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55672
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e588 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54744
6   libclient.dylib                 0x26124931 jio_vsnprintf + 321
7   libclient.dylib                 0x2612486a jio_vsnprintf + 122
8   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 17 Crashed:  Java: VM Thread
0   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00d96f10 std::_Rb_tree<CImplBase*, CImplBase*, std::_Identity<CImplBase*>, std::less<CImplBase*>, std::allocator<CImplBase*> >::find(CImplBase* const&) + 32
1   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00d96f68 std::set<CImplBase*, std::less<CImplBase*>, std::allocator<CImplBase*> >::find(CImplBase* const&) + 24
2   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0092b536 0x1000 + 9610550
3   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x008a7a37 0x1000 + 9071159
4   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0011ea1d 0x1000 + 1169949
5   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x00123f24 0x1000 + 1191716
6   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x0021b553 0x1000 + 2205011
7   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x008fe8d3 0x1000 + 9427155
8   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x008fe975 0x1000 + 9427317
9   com.adobe.flash-10.0            0x001355f6 0x1000 + 1263094
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907b43bf __cxa_finalize + 208
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907b42d4 exit + 33
12  libclient.dylib                 0x2623dce6 JVM_Halt + 726
13  libclient.dylib                 0x2623dcad JVM_Halt + 669
14  libclient.dylib                 0x2620b207 JVM_EnableCompiler + 14471
15  libclient.dylib                 0x2620b119 JVM_EnableCompiler + 14233
16  libclient.dylib                 0x261a413b JVM_Lseek + 143243
17  libclient.dylib                 0x261a3c8a JVM_Lseek + 142042
18  libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
19  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
20  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 18:  Java: Reference Handler
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x261b8c95 JVM_MonitorWait + 5461
5   libclient.dylib                 0x261b7bfe JVM_MonitorWait + 1214
6   libclient.dylib                 0x261b787a JVM_MonitorWait + 314
7   ???                             0x2dc32839 0 + 767764537
8   ???                             0x2dc2adb1 0 + 767733169
9   ???                             0x2dc2adb1 0 + 767733169
10  ???                             0x2dc282d3 0 + 767722195
11  libclient.dylib                 0x261a57d0 JVM_Lseek + 149024
12  libclient.dylib                 0x261a5576 JVM_Lseek + 148422
13  libclient.dylib                 0x261b711b JVM_InternString + 2123
14  libclient.dylib                 0x261b6f8a JVM_InternString + 1722
15  libclient.dylib                 0x261b6d74 JVM_InternString + 1188
16  libclient.dylib                 0x261b680f JVM_StartThread + 2175
17  libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
18  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
19  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 19:  Java: Finalizer
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x261b8c95 JVM_MonitorWait + 5461
5   libclient.dylib                 0x261b7bfe JVM_MonitorWait + 1214
6   libclient.dylib                 0x261b787a JVM_MonitorWait + 314
7   ???                             0x2dc32839 0 + 767764537
8   ???                             0x2dc2adb1 0 + 767733169
9   ???                             0x2dc2af17 0 + 767733527
10  ???                             0x2dc2af17 0 + 767733527
11  ???                             0x2dc282d3 0 + 767722195
12  libclient.dylib                 0x261a57d0 JVM_Lseek + 149024
13  libclient.dylib                 0x261a5576 JVM_Lseek + 148422
14  libclient.dylib                 0x261b711b JVM_InternString + 2123
15  libclient.dylib                 0x261b6f8a JVM_InternString + 1722
16  libclient.dylib                 0x261b6d74 JVM_InternString + 1188
17  libclient.dylib                 0x261b680f JVM_StartThread + 2175
18  libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
19  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
20  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 20:  Java: Surrogate Locker Thread (CMS)
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e928 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55672
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e4a9 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54521
6   libclient.dylib                 0x261ce097 JVM_IsPrimitiveClass + 7639
7   libclient.dylib                 0x261cdc11 JVM_IsPrimitiveClass + 6481
8   libclient.dylib                 0x261b6d74 JVM_InternString + 1188
9   libclient.dylib                 0x261b680f JVM_StartThread + 2175
10  libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 21:  Java: Signal Dispatcher
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610d9a2 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 51698
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610d8ba JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 51466
6   libclient.dylib                 0x26210564 JVM_MonitorNotify + 1588
7   libclient.dylib                 0x261cec52 JVM_IsPrimitiveClass + 10642
8   libclient.dylib                 0x261ce92e JVM_IsPrimitiveClass + 9838
9   libclient.dylib                 0x261b6d74 JVM_InternString + 1188
10  libclient.dylib                 0x261b680f JVM_StartThread + 2175
11  libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
13  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 22:  Java: CompilerThread0
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e928 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55672
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e4a9 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54521
6   libclient.dylib                 0x261cfec2 JVM_IsPrimitiveClass + 15362
7   libclient.dylib                 0x261cfc9b JVM_IsPrimitiveClass + 14811
8   libclient.dylib                 0x261b6d74 JVM_InternString + 1188
9   libclient.dylib                 0x261b680f JVM_StartThread + 2175
10  libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 23:  Java: Low Memory Detector
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e928 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55672
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e588 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54744
6   libclient.dylib                 0x261d3e32 JVM_IsPrimitiveClass + 31602
7   libclient.dylib                 0x261b6d74 JVM_InternString + 1188
8   libclient.dylib                 0x261b680f JVM_StartThread + 2175
9   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 24:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9079535a semaphore_timedwait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2ea1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1066
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907f1a28 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971e2465 TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 242
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x971e21a3 TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 511
5   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x972063eb TimerThread + 97
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 25:  Java: SIGTERM handler
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907952fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90795a67 mach_msg + 68
2   libclient.dylib                 0x2610ef23 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57203
3   libclient.dylib                 0x2610edab JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56827
4   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e928 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55672
5   libclient.dylib                 0x2610e4a9 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54521
6   libclient.dylib                 0x2620a46f JVM_EnableCompiler + 10991
7   libclient.dylib                 0x2623dbf8 JVM_Halt + 488
8   libclient.dylib                 0x2623dacb JVM_Halt + 187
9   libjava.jnilib                  0x21c54b2b Java_java_lang_Shutdown_halt0 + 17
10  ???                             0x2dc32839 0 + 767764537
11  ???                             0x2dc2adb1 0 + 767733169
12  ???                             0x2dc2adb1 0 + 767733169
13  ???                             0x2dc2adb1 0 + 767733169
14  ???                             0x2dc2b28d 0 + 767734413
15  ???                             0x2dc2b28d 0 + 767734413
16  ???                             0x2dc282d3 0 + 767722195
17  libclient.dylib                 0x261a57d0 JVM_Lseek + 149024
18  libclient.dylib                 0x261a5576 JVM_Lseek + 148422
19  libclient.dylib                 0x261b711b JVM_InternString + 2123
20  libclient.dylib                 0x261b6f8a JVM_InternString + 1722
21  libclient.dylib                 0x261b6d74 JVM_InternString + 1188
22  libclient.dylib                 0x261b680f JVM_StartThread + 2175
23  libclient.dylib                 0x2610e33b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 54155
24  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c2a19 _pthread_start + 345
25  libSystem.B.dylib               0x907c289e thread_start + 34

Thread 26:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907babd2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bb168 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bad86 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 27:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907babd2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bb168 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x907bad86 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 17 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000a70  ebx: 0x0092b51a  ecx: 0x000000ca  edx: 0xb10a9bc0
  edi: 0x3bd00002  esi: 0x00000a60  ebp: 0xb10a9b78  esp: 0xb10a9b50
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x00d96f10   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00000a70

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -  0x123eff0 +com.adobe.flash-10.0 10.0.2.566 (10.0.2) <A7C69920-4EEA-48D1-9C7E-9895FBF62001> /Applications/Adobe Flash CS4/Adobe Flash CS4.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash CS4
 0x1728000 -  0x17fafe7 +AdobeAXEDOMCore ??? (???) /Applications/Adobe Flash CS4/Adobe Flash CS4.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeAXEDOMCore.framework/Versions/A/AdobeAXEDOMCore
 0x18ae000 -  0x193b2cb +libicucnv.dylib.36.0 36.0.0 (compatibility 36.0.0) /Applications/Adobe Flash CS4/Adobe Flash
```

Comment: I think Steve Jobs is trying to give you a hint - "flash is evil, thou shall not use it!"... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the suggestions [in this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2397055#2397055):

*Try removing the font Franklin Gothic as this has worked for many users who were experiencing Flash crashes.*

*Even if it isn't this particular font causing the problem, I would look closely at your fonts. Perhaps try moving them all to a folder on the desktop and then re-introduce a few at a time until the culprit is found.*

Comment: I was able to narrow it down to a font issue. Thanks again Adobe for another 6 hours of life lost!

Comment: Nice to hear this worked out for you. Welcome to StackOverflow btw.